# Perform diff() on a subset of dataframe columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with a dozen columns and I'd like to do a `diff()` on only about half of them, keeping the result unchanged.

Currently I've got:

```py
df = ... # input dataframe

diff_cols = ['fizz', 'buzz', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']

for dc in diff_cols:
    df[dc] = df[dc].diff()
```

Is there a canonical approach?

Comment: You have: [series.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) . You want [dataframe.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Comment: no youre not using dataframe diff, df[dc] is a series

Comment: @user17 you are correct, I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually do

```
diff_cols = ['fizz', 'buzz', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
df[diff_cols] = df[diff_cols].diff()
```